# Which converges faster, mean or median?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, median

If I draw i.i.d. variables from N(0,1), will the mean or the median converge faster?  How much faster?

To be more specific, let $x_1, x_2, \ldots $ be a sequence of i.i.d. variables drawn from N(0,1).  Define $\bar{x}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and $\tilde{x}_n$ to be the median of $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n\}$.  Which converges to 0 faster, $\{\bar{x}_n\}$ or $\{\tilde{x}_n\}$?

For concreteness on what it means to converge faster: does $\lim_{n \to \infty} Var(\bar{X}_n)/Var(\tilde{X}_n)$ exist?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you asking about the convergence in probability of a point estimate with respect to the population parameter? Or are you asking about the convergence in distribution of a random variable?

Comment: By "converge faster to 0" do you mean "which has the smaller asymptotic variance" or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b To some extent this is motivated by a real problem : the median is more robust against outliers, so it seems like the sample median should converge more rapidly than the mean  as the sample size grows.  I don't really know what the best way of expressing the rate of convergence is in this situation.  For concreteness, I could ask whether $\lim_{n \to \infty} Var(\bar{X}_n)/Var(\tilde{X}_n)$ exists, and if so, what it is.

Comment: If the data are truly sampled from a normal distribution, outliers are extremely rare - so rare that the impact on the mean leaves the sample mean as the most efficient estimate of the population mean. But you don't need a vary heavy tail to make the median competitive. That ratio you mention will indeed be about 0.63

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mean and median are the same, in this particular case. It is known that the median is 64% efficient as the mean, so the mean is faster to converge. I can write more details but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_%28statistics%29#Asymptotic_efficiency) deals with your question exactly.

Comment: Do you have a citation?

Comment: Laplace, P.S.de (1818) *Deuxième supplément à la Théorie Analytique des Probabilités*, Paris, Courcier -- Laplace gives the asymptotic distribution for both mean and median. See also  the section on the variance of the median on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Variance)

Comment: @Glen_b: (+1) the ultimate reference!!!

Comment: @Glen_b yeah that was an epic response, I laughed pretty hard. Thanks for that!

Comment: @xi'an did you mean to write that the mean and median are the same quantity?

Comment: My reference is probably not as impressive as the one @Glen_b provided. I remember that it is in Bulmer's Principles of Statistics. But I think for your case the refrence I added in my answer suffices.

Comment: There is a confusion there: the theoretical mean and variances of the normal distribution are the same quantity. However, the empirical mean and median of a normal sample are not the same.